# netstat command on WSL doesn't give any messages

Tags: netstat

```
$ netstat -nap
(No info could be read for "-p": geteuid()=1000 but you should be root.)
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
Active UNIX domain sockets (servers and established)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   PID/Program name     Path
```

`nestat` command gives no information about ports are using. For example, I'm running redis-server on this PC but it is not displayed here.

How to I fix this? Linux distro is Microsoft WSL Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: the bracketed line is your clue; your UID.  You need elevated privileges to have rights to access the data you want so what you're seeing is very restricted.  try using `sudo netstat -nap` instead

Comment: @guiverc `sudo netstat -nap` gives me same output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/proc/net/tcp` is not implemented for WSL, hence accessing these networking `proc` interfaces does not work. The `netstat` or `ss` commands access these and, since they are not implemented, they do not work in WSL on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

From Windows PowerShell, running the command `Get-NetTCPConnection` gives the equivalent netstat output